# File Upload With Loopback

Tags: jquery, node.js, file-upload, loopbackjs, google-api-nodejs-client

I created a simple file uploading application with loopbackjs. 
In the application's client side I used simple HTML and Javascript code, calling a loopback api with an AJAX call:

```
$('#upload-input').on('change', function () {

    var files = $(this).get(0).files;

    if (files.length > 0) {
        // One or more files selected, process the file upload
        var form = new FormData();

        for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {

            var file = files[index];
            form.append('Uploded Files', file, file.name);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/fileupload/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('upload successful!');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

We are not getting files on the server side. On the server side we created a Loopback API, but how can we upload files with this API?

This is my loopback API code:

```
FileUpload.remoteMethod

(
        'upload', {
            http: {
                verb: 'post',
            },
            accepts:
            [
                { arg: 'ctx', type: 'object', http: { source: 'context' } },
                { arg: 'options', type: 'object', http: { source: 'query' } }

            ],
            returns: {
                arg: 'data',
                type: 'string',
                root: true
            }
        }
    );

    FileUpload.upload = function (context, options, callback) {
        //context.req.params = 'common';

    };
```

Comment: did u check loopback-storage-component - http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html

Comment: Yes , But how  can we used it !! please clarify

Comment: Thanks , we need to store files on Server side  not in Container  .

Comment: check the link, it has steps to implement it, also link to example - https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-storage

Comment: Conatiners are nothing but folders on server side, will give another option as answer as it won't fit in comment box

Comment: thanks Again , Actually Our Problem is that , we need to upload a File from Client Side and Store this File in Database , But Before save in DB , we need to get files on Server side , if we get Files on Server side via Post API than we can easily store file in DB .

Comment: on Server Side We are using Loopback APIs , So we are not able to get the uploaded file Properties .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install multer : https://github.com/expressjs/multer

```
npm install --save multer
```

In MyModel.js

```
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function (MyModel) {
    var uploadedFileName = '';
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            // checking and creating uploads folder where files will be uploaded
            var dirPath = 'client/uploads/'
            if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
                var dir = fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
            }
            cb(null, dirPath + '/');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            // file will be accessible in `file` variable
            var ext = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf("."));
            var fileName = Date.now() + ext;
            uploadedFileName = fileName;
            cb(null, fileName);
        }
    });


    MyModel.upload = function (req, res, cb) {
        var upload = multer({
            storage: storage
        }).array('file', 12);
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                // An error occurred when uploading
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                res.json(uploadedFileName);
            }
        });        
    };

    MyModel.remoteMethod('upload',   {
        accepts: [{
            arg: 'req',
            type: 'object',
            http: {
                source: 'req'
            }
        }, {
            arg: 'res',
            type: 'object',
            http: {
                source: 'res'
            }
        }],
        returns: {
             arg: 'result',
             type: 'string'
        }
    });
};
```

Frontend - I use AngularJS, so for that follow -https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

there are also other such directives to use

P.S. - As per your comment - `Actually Our Problem is that , we need to upload a File from Client Side and Store this File in Database , But Before save in DB , we need to get files on Server side , if we get Files on Server side via Post API than we can easily store file in DB`

Can't provide you exact solution, but using above method files will be uploaded in your `/client/uploads` folder, once uploaded then you have control on what to do with file and once everything is done, eventually delete it(optional)

Comment: Unhandled error for request POST /api/fileupload/upload: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)

Comment: I think its generate error here-                         
res.json(uploadedFileName);

Comment: can you console `file` variable near,  // file will be accessible in `file` variable and check if you get anything there

Comment: Control is not going there , so its Print nothing ,  I am putting my code please check if something missing .

Comment: @Aks1357 its working fine. but res.end(result) not showing any data.

Comment: @Santhosh - cannot provide a proper solution until I see your modified code. Try replicating to the above code.  Debug with multiple `console.log` as by which point you getting the value, and where it's getting empty.

Comment: @Aks1357 i am debugging to get the res.end(result) as expected value. but postman response showing only 204 No Content.

Comment: @Aks1357 It's my modified code: https://github.com/santhosharuchamy/loopback-file-upload/blob/90a7ac8ececa7a73b38aad5b6715aba26a260599/Loopback%20custom%20fileupload.js#L80

Comment: @Santhosh, try to debug by `console.log(result)` before fs.unlink, if the result is getting printed. Or try using res.send() or res.json() instead res.end()

Comment: @Jayesh_naik  console.log(result) print the value  before fs.unlink i am checking but not return any response in postman only showing the 204 No Content..

Comment: i am tried these res.send() or res.json() or res.end() but not working

Comment: @Jayesh_naik i am tried these res.send() or res.json() or res.end() but not working

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code:

```
module.exports = function (FileUpload) {
var multer = require('multer');

    FileUpload.remoteMethod(
        'upload', {
            http: {
                verb: 'post',
            },
            accepts:
            [{
                arg: 'req',
                type: 'object',
                http: {
                    source: 'req'
                }
            }, {
                arg: 'res',
                type: 'object',
                http: {
                    source: 'res'
                }
            }],
            returns: {
                arg: 'data',
                type: 'string',
                root: true
            }
        }
    );

    var uploadedFileName = '';

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            // checking and creating uploads folder where files will be uploaded
            var dirPath = 'client/uploads/'
            if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
                var dir = fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
            }
            cb(null, dirPath + '/');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            // file will be accessible in `file` variable
            console.log("----------Second Rakesh---");
            console.log(file);
            var ext = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf("."));
            var fileName = Date.now() + ext;
            uploadedFileName = fileName;
            cb(null, fileName);
        }
    });

    FileUpload.upload = function (req, res, callback) {

        var upload = multer({
            storage: storage
        }).array('file', 12);

        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                // An error occurred when uploading
                res.json(err);
            }
            console.log("-------------Rakesh"); // Its Printing Rakesh

            res.json(uploadedFileName);
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: control is not printing -                                                             
                                 console.log("----------Second Rakesh---");

Comment: Add `var fs = require('fs');` after `multer` as we are using that also, so it was not declared in the code but was used, which generated error

Comment: Thank you very much , do you see my code ? You mean , after  var multer = require('multer'); we need to add var fs = require('fs');

Comment: Thanks , But it showing Error -  Unhandled error for request POST /api/fileupload/upload: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.  and it also not Printing Console.log(file).

Comment: When I print 'storage' in console it show me -                             
  DiskStorage {
  getFilename: [Function: filename],
  getDestination: [Function: destination]                                                       
 }

Comment: control not printing 'file' object near '// file will be accessible in `file` variable'  in console !! Please check my code .

Comment: I replaced res.json(err); with  res.end("File is uploaded"); After Changing Error - Unhandled error for request POST /api/fileupload/upload: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.                                                
Solved .  But file not uploading !!!!!!!

Comment: changing that, doesn't matter much, console `err` and change `if` to `if else`

Comment: Thanks , now  its Working. can you tell me about Authentication and Security to Loopback API . How can i implement it in my Project.

Comment: sure, what are you using, angularJS..? links to get started - http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html , http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Create-AngularJS-client.html

Comment: Actually , For now i am not using AngularJs , I need to do in loopback. can we do only with loopback and NodeJS .

Comment: can you guide me for Authentication-authorization to loopback apis.

Comment: i go through http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html#preparing-access-control-models but i can not get that where i need to start. please tell me what i need to do !!!!

Comment: it's a very topic which cannot be covered here, you are on the right link, please follow steps the have mentioned like creating this file `server/boot/authentication.js` and `copy pasting` the code they have given, just follow the steps mentioned in the documentation

Comment: can you give me source code for Reference !! if possible

Comment: can you tell me "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false,
    "relations": {
      "user": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "user",
        "foreignKey": "userId"
      }
    }                              here what is userid???

Comment: check this example, source code is also provided - https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control

Comment: I am following this link https://strongloop.com/strongblog/working-with-loopback-authentication-and-authorization/ and create same Project , but i am getting this error- TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object .

Comment: This is Git url- https://github.com/cfjedimaster/StrongLoopDemos/blob/master/simpleauthdemo/server/boot/authentication.js

Comment: This is error-POST /api/appusers/login: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Please check this Question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513313/how-to-add-authentication-to-loopback-custom-api

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files/Images using loopback's default [storage component](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage). Go to the [doc link](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage) and follow the instruction and specially look how the example project implemented the file uploading.

You will have to create a datasource and a container model for this purpose.

Create Datasource:

```
$ lb datasource
[?] Enter the data-source name: myfilesystem
[?] Select the connector for myfilesystem: other
[?] Enter the connector name: loopback-component-storage
[?] Install storage (Y/n)
```

create the container model:

- **Model name**: Container
- **Data source**: myfilesystem
- **Base class**: Model
- **Expose Reviewer via the REST API?** Yes
- **Custom plural form (used to build REST URL)**:  Yes

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using **LoopbackJs**

Loopback framework is **based on ExpressJs** by the way

You can consider this answer as and **adapted version** of https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/ for  LoopbackJs

Install plugin dependecy:

```
npm install jquery-file-upload-middleware
```

Add this snippet to your /server/server.js :

```
 //Load Jquery File Upload handler
      var upload = require('jquery-file-upload-middleware'),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser');

        // configure upload middleware
        upload.configure({
            uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads',
            uploadUrl: '/uploads',
            imageVersions: {
                thumbnail: {
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80
                }
            }
        });



        app.use('/upload', upload.fileHandler());
        app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }))
```

Modify middleware.js with the following snippet so your app can **serve static HTML resources** in /client folder (this file belongs LoopbackJs framework BTW):

```
...
    "files": {
  "loopback#static": {
    "params": "$!../client" 
  }
}
...
```

Download and place in /client/test file-upload webpage  :
[File Upload Webpage](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/releases)

Run your node.app and point to **http://localhost:3000/files/**
You should be able to upload files and found the uploaded filename response in the Network tab:

[image]