# loopback 3 file storage connector

Tags: jquery, ajax, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I am new to loopback and i have a form where have the some fields with file upload. now i am able to store the field values using the PersistedModel with mysql database.

I want to save the file upload also in some location.how to do this can anyone explain with example. I have seen the loopback 3 storage documentation, but i couldn't get. I am using the dropzone js for file upload.
Here is my code

```
<form  id="myForm" novalidate>
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required>
         <div class="invalid-feedback">Please Enter a Valid Email Id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <input type="text" id="role" name="role" class="form-control" placeholder="Job Role" >
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="resume" class="dropzone form-control"></div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-10" id="item-submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var parms = {
   firstname : $("#firstname").val(),
   email : $("#email").val(),
   role : $("#role").val(),
   message: $("#message").val()
   };
   $.ajax({
   method: 'POST',
   url:  "http://localhost:3000/api/careers",
   async: false,
   dataType : "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify(parms),
   success: function(data){
   console.log('Submission was successful.');
   // location.reload();
   console.log(data);
   }, error: function (data) {
      console.log('An error occurred.');
      console.log(data);
         },   
      })
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to upload a file with text fields and store them into database also the same time store the file into some path in your directory right ? 

Do you want to use AJAX or normal uploading method in PHP/NodeJS ?

Comment: @Googlian  yes i want to store the field values and the file

Comment: in PHP or NodeJS ?

Comment: NodeJS am using only loopback 3 for backend

Comment: What is your backend code ? Can you put the back-end sample code

Comment: loopback model {
  "name": "career","base": "PersistedModel","idInjection": true,"options": {"validateUpsert": true  },
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "number" },"firstname": {"type": "string","required": true },"email": {"type": "string","required": true},"role": {"type": "string","required": true},
    "message": {"type": "string","required": true },"resume": {"type": "string"} },
  "validations": [], "relations": {},"acls": [],"methods": {}
  }

Comment: Did you refer https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Storage-component.html

Comment: yes am using loopback3

Comment: for upload can you use express with multer

Comment: how to use can u pls give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Use `express.js` with `multer` to easily upload files and insert database.

Multer is a node.js middleware for handling `multipart/form-data`, which is primarily used for uploading files. It is written on top of busboy for maximum efficiency.

**Install `express` and `multer`**

```
npm install --save multer
npm install --save express
```

---

**app.js** in back-end

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer');

const port = 3000

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {

    var fileName = req.file.originalname

    // Do your database operations here
    console.log(fileName)

    res.send(req.file)
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))
```

**index.html** in front-end

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but with loopback3 is it not possible

Comment: possible but it's more complicated than this way, if you want you can follow loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Storage-component.html

Comment: Kindly consider to accept the answer if you feel it's helpful

Comment: I need to use with loopback 3 only. so help me on this

Comment: Did you refer this http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Storage-component.html

Comment: I have refered, but my doubt is where is the path for the file storage

Comment: without sowing the back-end code we cannot decide on that could you please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409570/file-upload-with-loopback

Answer (score 0):

I also have a similar implementation [check this out](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component-REST-API.html)

However, you need to specify the storage container you are using in the datasources.json file
Here's My implementation of the storage connector.

```
localstorage: {
    "name": "localstorage",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "root": "./files/",
    "nameConflict": "makeUnique",
    "maxFileSize": "104857600"
}
```

and in model-config.json add this:

```
"Container": {
    "dataSource": "localstorage",
    "public": true
},
```

also don't forget to add **Container.json** in **common/models** folder which would look like this:

```
{
   "name": "Container",
   "base": "Model"
}
```

Now you will be able to post the files to "/api/container" path